# Tag Synonym: cell-phone -> mobile-phones

Tags: feature-request

Didn't there use to be an interface to propose synonyms? I can't find it now.

Anyway, [cell-phone](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell-phone) and [mobile-phones](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-phones) should be merged.

Wikipedia prefers [Mobile phone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone).

As an Australian, I'm biased to prefer "mobile phone". "Cell phone" seems to be US-centric.

Comment: Thanks, @Yannis. It makes sense. I only had access when I didn't need it!